# Sitecore 10 - Reset admin password when you cannot log in

Tags: sitecore

I have installed **Sitecore 10** on my local machine for development but have forgotton the master admin password. So now I am not able to log into sitecore from the browser.

I would like to know about how to reset this admin password.

Please give me detailed steps and not just a update query from other posts which I have tried and it has not worked.

Thanks a ton in Advance :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it programmaticaly or reset it in the SQL database, but with SQL that depend on the hash algorithm configured. Therefore your previous scripts may not work, programmatically works independently of the hash algorithm.

Programmatically reset password to b:

```
string userName = "sitecore\\admin";
var user = Membership.GetUser(userName);
user.UnlockUser();
user.ChangePassword(user.ResetPassword(), "b");
```

See for compleet ready to use script:

http://www.stockpick.nl/english/how-to-add-a-sitecore-admin-programmatically/

https://github.com/jbluemink/Sitecore-Admin-Scripts-for-Development-and-Deploying